# Detect pixel perfect collision between two AnimatedSprite?

Tags: android, andengine, collision-detection

How do I detect a collision between two AnimatedSprite in andengine? I tried the collidesWith of AndEngineCollsionsExtension function but I detect collisions with transparent pixels.

This is my code:

```
private BitmapTextureAtlas mSpriteTexture; 
private PixelPerfectTiledTextureRegion mSpriteTextureRegion; 
private PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite sprite; 

private BitmapTextureAtlas mObstaculoBajo_TextureAtlas; 
private PixelPerfectTiledTextureRegion mObstaculoBajo_TextureRegion; 
private PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite mObstaculoBajo1; 

private CollisionLogger spriteCollisionLog;

spriteCollisionLog = new CollisionLogger("SpriteColl");

spriteCollisionLog.startCollisionCheck (); 
sprite.collidesWith collisionResult = boolean (mObstaculoBajo1); 
spriteCollisionLog.endCollisionCheck (collisionResult); 
if (collisionResult) 
{
 showToast ("Collision"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is check the distance between two sprites center points if it is less than the width of sprites ignoring transparent region then you can say they are colliding.. Another way if you are using sprites of irregular shape then Subclass the Sprite and override colideswith property and check the collision area pixel color...

Also there is pixel perfect colision extension play with its  thershold for alpha proprty

Checkout this
 It is fast (with a few collision it easily runs at 60FPS on my very low-end ZTE blade)
    you set the threshold for alpha
    it supports pixel perfect collision against whatever rectangle shape (that means that if you have a star as a pixelperfect sprite and a cube as a normal sprite, when the cube do not touch the effective star, the collision check will return false)
    it has different tools for debug (a logger to see performance, an utility method to see the solid mask, ..)
    it is really easy to use: just use PixelPerfectSprite and PixelPerfectAnimatedSprite instead of the normal ones

You can find the extension here
https://github.com/MakersF/AndEngineCollisionsExtension

Comment: The extension trying collision with andengine but I must be missing something because it detects collision although pixels are transparent.